# oracle check constraint "in" clause and "like" clause

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, check-constraints

I would like to know what is the different between 'in' clause and 'like' clause oracle in check constraint.

here is sample code for 'in' clause

```
ALTER TABLE EXPREPORT
ADD CONSTRAINT EXPREPORT_CHK1 CHECK 
(EXPREPSTATUS IN ('PENDING', 'APPROVED', 'DENIED'))
ENABLE;
```

here is sample code for 'like' clause

```
ALTER TABLE EXPENSEREPORT
ADD CONSTRAINT EXPENSEREPORT_CHK1 CHECK 
(EXPREPSTATUS LIKE 'APPROVED' OR EXPREPSTATUS LIKE 'DENIED' OR EXPREPSTATUS LIKE 'PENDING')
ENABLE;
```

is there any difference between these two clause?

Comment: In this exact case, there should be no difference. If you add wildcards to your strings to match, the difference will be the same as using `LIKE` vs. using `=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LIKE    column value is similar to specified character(s).

IN  column value is equal to any one of a specified set of values.

[Click Here](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-like-in-operators.htm) for more information about LIKE and IN clause.

Comment: In general, yes, `like` and `in` conditions are different, but the way OP is using them (`like` without wildcard characters equal to `=` operator) in his/her example, there is no difference between those two statements.

Comment: I gave one link right. u will get detailed information here. Can u refer once that tutorial. If still u get doubt means will clear it.